# How validate token (not JWT) using certificate?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, access-token, .net-6.0, x509certificate2

Ciao. In our .NET Framework project we are receiving token generated by third party app. In our side we validate it using DotNetOpenAuth nuget.

```
 var request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = authHeaderValue;
                      
            var resourceServer = 
                new ResourceServer(
                    new StandardAccessTokenAnalyzer(
                        (RSACryptoServiceProvider)SigningCertificate.PublicKey.Key,
                        (RSACryptoServiceProvider)EncryptionCertificate.PrivateKey));

            var response = resourceServer.VerifyAccess(request, requestUri, out var result);
                return response != null ? null : result;
```

Where **SigningCertificate** and **EncryptionCertificate** its the same **X509Certificate2**.

But now we need to move this logic to a new app .net6 where we cant use DotNetOpenAuth. What we only have it's certificate witch **DotNetOpenAuth** use to validate and get **IPrincipal** from token.

Token like:

"gAAAALvOC0BP347GfaIktPPc5mv6YmAEAeMtOy-9tQ-8lSbAQYu_UqOn8fr4sMdtPCR2Kyi63TwG9dRg85CWSqv5yVm7FzlWegiL5V3hzzP9D-gFHV8ZsONL-8hRD-akZqx7UMw_Y-uwJ1CMk0AYunPGGG2jnoUWQ_0F15q4YlwDOZM7BAMAAIAAAACYePO3rdZIyzvQfJWJV5qT7YQ2LHoKqLK517NGAwqsda3MozSVo4JULa60uYqI-okwPkXDf7B0b-9td2U_fKqf0LYMUnOnwMglE7W_nI6PjAUvVjM5kmKC2odzQLmhQYhqjWKJ4UHeoCa23VGgeKn15CGyb0SvBWnwBgSD3tH-4l_j1iea-PmlkNq6o4eF5LQkkt0FPZrQMRic1H8v15PeeRbKcDF6xIMXRc0CN0H61kVrn1UfaSiDrR4tsbKDaSd_hjE-pLxppr2tqyJwNa7FVuaNxvBciJ5vVypKtlWLYnPEkjTgep6FnOkOFpyPVA5Be3QIBlFZe3bHmLxbAJTR73dZpvCy_2nL9Dxlkj-*Ulq20ui8REfslEUvm40-f2QFUfCnq1TYZsp-NwpXVUsJiwc0CsZljaHbB73CIQCHhw6gKCODF6C4BDa2HwuGTcyIM6SKhCUxLu874Gdj61D_QSwNMdMlNAzNWJ_cl0QTtUqj-7eMyEg8dhsdWrHqUdUiKl8DSwX7bazVPvJuKNfKQSwR93sIoKWnZ-nXDpP6KwRi30gSPzr_3HyOfyZSCsSSnD36RDCGxZg_6cgC6yZJpNy2tsR0IS7nqJj0qpV63AouiaehcMiP4QwUUiidohFfz3SwRmOSZcS_fUFvnxoVist4wnQCYnAai__NLx2S6E5*-3Z9tHLqr5opj1HzF2XOHONAFD1tRs0ZsxQtb39Rd0etfRuHsbQ4pM0abaLQGWAV6kRlMUwPhTBJ8XTjooRzWZwMCxvmXJ4jfb2TNxtmG4nFEd3S5SuoHLgW8khYk66Pc0eP3BYWfylNZ5YRBsf1FCGzHGmriLqyJjpQMNPcosIGhtxyEOhtU6wE9lido7sZWhsWM5HKLvqIAkzjPOA_YcFyvxmxZn3a3BQVwIL3X9D9bKr1fxYOMomIMraX01keLuB5gYb5D8te186HS3mTgBxdTyZn-sdVlXRQau3kNaHbiBtjPqbtWNuuv-RFYmvkDRKUcXsaO2qrbZUkMz4"

So, can I somehow validate and get some data from this token using this certificate?

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth is opensource and code is available at [github](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth) you can check the code how they are doing and replicate same.

Comment: maybe, but for exempla  it use RSACryptoServiceProvider which is not available for .net6

Comment: @РомаМатковский Yes of course [it's available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=net-6.0) for .net6.